# Getting rendered body

Tags: php, twig, slim

I've been working with slim framework and I found a problem. I'm using mpdf library to generate pdf files out of the html content I'm passing to it. I'm also using Twig Templating Engine for (I think) obvious reasons. My problem is that I can't access body rendered by Slim Twig View, at the time the controller is working, because the data is still in the output buffer. I've made a workaround by creating middleware class intercepting a request with specific route and generating the pdf file from it's body but I don't think that's the way it's supposed to be done. I was also trying not to mess with ob_get_contents in the controller because that's like working against the framework.

So here is my question: Is there a better way to do what I did?

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to get the view to generate a pdf rather than trying to get the controller to capture what the view has done then change it to a pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig's core library contains a class called Twig_Environment, which is used for rendering views. This class has these methods:

```
$twig->display('view.html.twig', $variables);
```

This will immediately output the generated content, which is not what you want for your PDF. You want this method:

```
$content = $twig->render('view.html.twig', $variables);
```

This method will return the generated HTML and won't echo it. You can then pass $content to your PDF library to convert it to PDF.

I don't know the framework you're using, you'll need to find a way to access the instance of the Twig_Environment class.

Comment: I am using Slim. I can't get it to work. my code: `$dompdf = new Dompdf(); $vars=['param'=>$param]; $content=$app->render('path/to/view.twig',$vars); $dompdf->loadHtml($content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream('proyectos.pdf');` I get the following error: `Requested HTML document contains no data.` How do I fix this?